# countable or not countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Good evening everyone;

Can you tell me whether are they countable or not ?
$$
2^\mathbb{R}\\
2^\mathbb{Z}\\
2^\mathbb{N}
$$
where $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of real numbers. $\mathbb{Z}$ is  set of integers. $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of natural numbers.

In my opinion, all of them are uncountable. However, I would like to hear your opinion.

Regards,

Comment: Good morning...

Comment: How $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ etc. are defined? If I mean $2^{\mathbb{N}} = \{2, 4, 8, \dots\}$ , it is definitely countable.

Comment: @HopelessFool In general, $A^B$ means the set of function from $B$ to $A$. (By Von Neumann's definition of ordinal) we define $2=\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** Recall that $|X|<|2^X|$, and that countable sets are those sets $A$ such that $|A|\leq|\Bbb N|$.

Answer (score 2):

I will just give you a hint: No, the sets are not countable. For the $2^\mathbb{N}$ case start by assuming that it is countable. Then take a bijection  $f: \mathbb{N} \to 2^\mathbb{N}$. Then consider the set
$$
X = \{n\in \mathbb{N} : n\notin f(n)\}.
$$
Now see if you can get a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: suppose $2^\mathbb N$ is countable. Then, construct a sequence whose $nth$ term is different from the $nth$ term of the $nth$ element of $2^ \mathbb N$. What's unusual about such a construction?